# django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot compute Foo('Bar'): 'Bar' is an aggregate

Tags: python, django

I have some models in django like this:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('type'), choices=ActivityTypeChoices.choices)

class UserActivity(BaseLogged):
    activity = models.ForeignKey(to='Activity', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(to='UserInterface', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Rule(models.Model):
    activity = models.ForeignKey(to=Activity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    condition = models.IntegerField()

class RuleSet(models.Model):
    """
    This model is used for checking one or more rule together.
    If all the rules are done, the set of rules is considered done
    """
    rules = models.ManyToManyField(to=Rule)

class RuleSetGroup(models.Model):
    """
    This model is used for checking one rule set among multiple rule sets.
    If one of the rule sets are done, the whole group of rule set is considered done.
    """
    rule_sets = models.ManyToManyField(to=RuleSet)
```

A `Rule` is done when the number of `UserActivities` with the same `activity` is more than the `condition`.

A `RuleSet` is done when all of its `rules` are done.

A `RuleSetGroup` is done when one of its `rule_sets` is done

How can I check if a `RuleSetGroup` is done or not?

I did something like this:

```
RuleSet.objects.annotate(done=Min(Case(When(Q(
    rules__condition__lte=Count('rules__activity__useractivity__user_id')
), then=1), default=0, output_field=IntegerField())))
```

But it raises this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot compute Min('<Case: CASE WHEN <Q: (AND: ('rules__condition__lte', Count(F(rules__activity__useractivity__us
er_id))))> THEN Value(1), ELSE Value(0)>'): '<Case: CASE WHEN <Q: (AND: ('rules__condition__lte', Count(F(rules__activity__useractivity__user_id))))>
 THEN Value(1), ELSE Value(0)>' is an aggregate
```

Although I did this wrong but this is not my goal. I want to know a `RuleSetGroup` is done or not